# how to solve numberformatexception and getting input string:""?

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

I am trying to make a program where The inputs consist of several lines, with the first line indicating the number of succeeding lines of character sequences. These character sequences will be splitted by " ". And the splitted characters will be converted into integer and get its sum.

```
  For Example:      
  2      
  2 3      
  4 5      

  2 3 Sum is 5
  4 5 Sum is 9
```

Now, When I input the same inputs, i get this..

```
  2
  2 3
  4 5
   Sum is 0
  2 3 Sum is 5
  4 5 Sum is 9

  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at ITweek.sum2(ITweek.java:33)
at ITweek.main(ITweek.java:18)
```

Why do I have a return of Sum is 0? and an error of NumberFormatException: For input string: ""? I don't get it. I don't know how and where to find the answer. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

This is my code..

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Prob {
      public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int loop = input.nextInt();

    String numberString[]=new String[loop+1];

    for(int i=0; i<=loop; i++){
        String ans = input.nextLine();
        numberString[i] = ans;
    }
    sum2(numberString);

}

  static void sum2(String []answers){
  for(String b : answers){
         System.out.print(""+b+" ");

         String splittedNumber[] = b.split(" ");

         int sum = 0;
         for(String j : splittedNumber){
             try{
                 sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(j);
             }catch(Exception x){
                 x.printStackTrace();
         }
         }
            System.out.println("Sum is "+sum);
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: If there is a " ",do not parse it to integer. A proper if-else statement will suffice.

Comment: ahh Ok I see.. One of my carelessness. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, obviously ;), it's in this part of code

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int loop = input.nextInt();

    String numberString[]=new String[loop]; //remove last block of array. +1 is useless

    for(int i=0; i<=loop; i++){
        String ans = input.nextLine();
        numberString[i] = ans;
    }
    sum2(numberString);

}
```

You read from the standard input. First you read an int and pass it to loop variable. Your error is in thinking that after reading the int, you jump to the next line, which is not true. After reading an int, your buffer is ready to start reading right after the first char.

Basically, your first input in the numberString array is a \n character. If you want to mix readInt and readLine, be sure that after readInt you indicate to read the rest of the line to let the buffer advance. You can either use readLine for both cases or use a readLine after readInt and throw the \n to the garbage.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int loop = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

String numberString[]=new String[loop]; //remove last block of array. +1 is useless

for(int i=0; i<loop; i++){
    String ans = input.nextLine();
    numberString[i] = ans;
}
sum2(numberString);
```

or

```
public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int loop = input.readInt());
input.readLine;
String numberString[]=new String[loop]; //remove last block of array. +1 is useless

for(int i=0; i<loop; i++){
    String ans = input.nextLine();
    numberString[i] = ans;
}
sum2(numberString);
```

Comment: Oh I see.. thanks for Integer.parseInt(input.readLine()); and changing the condition of for loop to i<loop .. =) Your help is appreciated. =)

Comment: I removed the +1 AND removed the = condition from the for block. Otherwise you would have ended suming again an empty String at the last iteration of the for loop. You welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint, take a look at this line: String numberString[]=new String[loop+1];
What size of array are you initilizing and how many items are you acually putting into it?

Comment: I added 1 on it because I'm having an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if I didn't.

Comment: Ah, that is because of another issue in your for loop. Sounds like a school assignment so I don't think your instructor would be happy if I give you more than hints :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in the `main` method which you need to fix.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//create a new scanner to read string as input doesn't advance to next line after  reading int
Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);
    int loop = input.nextInt();
//loop through to enter your input and process with method call.
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
//you just need one element array to store input string which is separated by whitespace
        String numberString[] = new String[1];
        numberString[0] = inputString.nextLine();
        sum2(numberString);
    }
```

NFE occurred because empty string was attempted for conversion to Integer. I hope it helps.